# typescript keyof typeof sibling prop

Tags: typescript

I want to make the type of a param be the key of a sibling param object.
(I'm pretty novice at Typescript )

This is where I am at right now:
[Here a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-keyof-typeof-sibling-param-w6hn3g?file=/src/index.ts)

```
export const colors = (
  keys: { [x: string]: string } = {},
  modes: ((c: { [key in keyof typeof keys]: string }) => object) | object = {},
  initialColorMode = 'light'
) => {
  return typeof modes === 'function' ? modes(keys) : modes
}

// example

colors(
  {
    white: '#FFFFFF',
    light: '#DFDFDD',
    dark: '#000000',
    yellow: '#FFB300',
    blue: '#0759F9',
  },
  (c) => ({
    light: {
      text: c.dark, // this `c` object should autocomplete the values
      background: c.white,
      primary: c.yellow,
    },
    dark: {
      text: c.light,
      background: c.dark,
      primary: c.blue,
    },
  }),
  'light'
)
```

Basically, I want to have autocomplete of the `c` param reference the keys of the `keys` param.

Hopefully, this is clear enough and someone can give me pointers.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] others could paste into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue to themselves.  So no undeclared types or values: `ColorMode`? `T`? `ColorOrNestedColorScale`? `omit`?  You should either declare these things or, better yet, *remove* them from your example code unless you're explicitly asking about them.

Comment: I am still confused. You typed the `modes` parameter to be function that returns a `string`, but it seems to return an object? You also said that `modes` might be string or a function, but your default value is an empty object?

Comment: [Here is a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-keyof-typeof-sibling-param-w6hn3g?file=/src/index.ts)
The sandbox context seems to provide some autocomplete/intellisense, but it's not coming from the `c` object itself.
Hope this help.